# How "universal type"profile is different from in-house or adhoc type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile

Today, I needed to create a new in-house provisioning profile at apple developer portal and everything went fine, until I get to the last page where I need to enter profile name. However, noticed the page shows "universal type" profile instead of in-house. Just wondering why it's called universal, is it somehow different from in-house (or the same), and why the page isn't showing in-house instead :) Just trying to be sure about what is happening beneath.

[image]